# import cloud Analyst to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, load-balancing

I am comparing load balancing algorithms in cloud computing for my master thesis, and after importing Cloud Analyst to Eclipse, I faced these errors.
I should add some additional load Balancing Algorithm to Cloud Analyst, can someone help me?
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVJnE.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Cloudsim / CloudAnalyst is referring to internal JDK classes that have been removed in later Java versions.  Assuming that you just trying to build and use it, the simple approach is to use the version of Java that CloudAnalyst was developed for; i.e. Java 8.

Hmmm ... it looks like the code is:

https://github.com/vondrt4/CloudAnalyst-interactive/blob/master/source/cloudsim/ext/gui/screens/ConfigureSimulationPanel.java

or similar.  I have a feeling that this is just a bug that has been lurking in the code for a long time.  I suspect that they were really intending to catch `java.text.ParseException`, but their IDE suggested `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.ParseException` instead.

Looking at the place where that exception is being caught, I can't see how it could possibly occur.  The code is trying to parse some characters taken from a `JTextField` using `Integer.parseInteger`.  That cannot throw an (Xerces internal) `ParseException`.

Note: this would be harmless on Java 8 and earlier.  It only causes problems in later releases because the exception class has been removed.